# Where should I write JSon processing script - java or javascript

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, rest

If this question is more appropriate for another forum please do point me to the same.

 I am writing a web application that would pull data in JSon format from a number of REST sources. The UI uses a number of javascript technologies like Knockout.js etc using which I am displaying graphs, charts etc.

I have written a mid-tier in java, that acts as a 'broker' between the java script and the REST sources - the idea is to make javascript layer REST calls agnostic to the user/user role etc and let the mid tier decide with REST server/endpoint to call.This java code calls the actual REST endpoints, and exposes a generic REST endpoint to be called by java script.

  The problem is that the json returned by most of the REST calls is of a different structure than the one that is required by my java script technologies ( they are a plain array of the data, while each java script component like graph need the data in a very specific format). Also I can in no way modify the source of those REST calls.

This means I will have to do some amount of processing on the json I receive.
My question is, where should I make this processing? Should I do it in the java script code or it would be more appropriate to do it in the java mid-tier code?

 A friend of mine suggested that I should do it in javascript because :

1. In future I might end up making  some REST calls directly from
   java script, and then I would end up similar logic  in two places -
   java script and java
2. JSon being JSon, javascript will have better handling capabilities
3. If I do it in java, I also increase the number of rest calls
   considerably.

I am a bit uncomfortable doing it in java script because:

1. I am not comfortable coding in javascript(I admit)
2. If written in java the logic executes on the server instead of users
   browser, which I expect to be faster.(A fast loading page is kind of
   a must have here)

Am I right or wrong? Any other pros/cons?

P.S. Not that I care so much, but down-voting/close voting without mentioning the reason doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I would do all the processing in the server side. Do you have a nodejs or just the java?

Comment: For now just a plain java servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not listen your friend. Both his arguments are wrong.

1. While you use Java server side it is a bad idea to call your providers directly from JavaScript. Use mixed patterns is very-very bad idea.
2. JSon handles easy and better in Java than in JavaScript disregarding that JSON is "**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation". Just pick a package you'd like better: Jackson, Gson or something else...

So... do it on server in Java. It is a proper place to do that.
You have trivial integration use case, when you need to transform data from external providers to the client required format.

Comment: Btw he also mentioned that this will increase the number of rest calls.. I am not sure if it is good or bad.

Comment: With code on server side it is up to you how many REST calls you'd like to do. That is about orchestration and integration. With JavaScript it is out of your control. It depends on your providers. Anyway both ways applicable. Make your decision and do not change it later. Server side is more preferable, but it is up to you and your preferences.